# Запрос для вывода статистики по отсчётам

Tags: sql, запрос, mysql

Есть таблица, куда в случайные моменты времени падают замеры (id_метрики, значение_метрики, UNIX timestamp):

```
mid    data    timestamp
```

Некоторые timestamp'ы идентичны для группы из нескольких замеров с разными `mid`.

Как оптимально запросить данные для построения графика всех метрик mid по времени?
Что-то вроде:

```
timestamp    mid1  mid2  mid3 .. midN  (перечислены все "засветившиеся" mid)
12345        NULL  34    23   .. 12
67890        5     NULL  11   .. 77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, MySQL не поддерживает конструкции типа PIVOT.
Тогда можно воспользоваться, например, таким [методом](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table).

Comment: спасибо! Подзабыл со времен MS SQL и Access про Pivot.

Comment: Гениально красивый метод!  Спасибо ещё раз. : )